# .htaccess DirectoryIndex first HTML file in folder

Tags: .htaccess

I have a directory in which there will only ever be one `.html` file, but I don't know what it will be called, as it is retrieved by an engine that I have no control over.

How can I make the `.htaccess` `DirectoryIndex` point to the first (and only) `.html` file it comes across?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DirectorIndex to `index.php` and write a small PHP script which does the following.  This will scan the directory for the first HTML file and redirect to that.

```
<?php
foreach( scandir('.') as $f ) {
    if ( preg_match( "/\.html$/", $f) == 1  ) {
        header( "Location: http://{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}/uri_path/$f", true, 302 );
        exit();
    }
}
header( 'Status: 404');
exit();
```

Comment: That's actually a great idea. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, you'll need to add in the dirpath as well

Comment: Do I actually even need the http:// and paths, given that the .html will be in the same for and the .php?

Comment: Weeeeellll yes and no.  `"Location: $f"` will work with most modern browsers, but the RFC for HTTP 1 says that the location should be a fully qualified URI, so when I redirect, I always specify the full URI just to be sure.  And make sure to do a 302 as the client browsers cache 301s and this will barf if and when the file changes.

Comment: BTW read the PHP docs on header() because there are some subtleties if you want Apache/whatever to pick up and handle the 404